# Квартал по дате

Tags: алгоритм, php

Надо написать вычисление квартала по дате.

Вычислил номер квартала:

```
$d1 = "2014-11-02";
$kv = intval((date('m', strtotime($d1)) + 2)/3)
```

Дальше задумался, как лучше вычислить границы квартала:

1. Прогонять все это через функцию date(), вычисляя месяцы по номеру квартала
2. Сложить строки: нк+год (нк=начало квартала), где нк будет браться из массива, что-то типо: array(1=>array("start" => "01.01", "end" => "31.03"), 2=>array("start" => "01.04", "end" => "30.06") ...)

или как лучше определить временные границы квартала?

---

На данный момент я сделал так:

```
    function getIntervalKv($d)
    {
        $cKv = array(
            1 => array("s" => "01.01.", "e" => "31.03."),
            2 => array("s" => "01.04.", "e" => "31.06."),
            3 => array("s" => "01.07.", "e" => "30.09."),
            4 => array("s" => "01.10.", "e" => "31.12."),
        );
        $kv = intval((date('m', strtotime($d)) + 2)/3);
        $y = date('y', strtotime($d));
        $sd = $cKv[$kv]['s'].$y;
        $ed = $cKv[$kv]['e'].$y;
        return array("sd" => $sd, "ed" => $ed);
    }
```

Comment: Что по поводу брать только месяц и идти - если < 4 то первый, иначе если <7 то второй ....?

Comment: @jimpanzer это для вычисление квартала? как вариант :)

Comment: зачем использовать всю дату, если нужен только месяц?

Comment: @jimpanzer, в принципе незачем. Можете предложить получше алгоритм?

Comment: Я же уже написал, что достаете только номер месяца и его анализируете.

Comment: @jimpanzer вообще для определения квартала я достаю только месяц. А как потом получить начало и конец квартала (с годом)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так:

```
function getIntervalKv($d){
  $kv = (int)((date('n', $d)-1)/3+1);
  $year = date('y', $d);
  return Array(
    'sd'=>date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,($kv-1)*3+1,1,$year)),
    'ed'=>date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,($kv)*3+1,0,$year)));
}
print_r(getIntervalKv(mktime(0,0,0,4, 1, 2007)));
```

> Array ( [sd] => 01-04-2007 [ed] => 30-06-2007 )

Comment: интересный вариант получить конец квартала :)

Comment: на самом деле, естественный. конец чего-то это чуть раньше чем начало следующего такого же.

Answer (score 2):

*И я хочу :)*

```
function getQuarterInterval($quarter, $year = NULL) {
    if (!$year)
    {
        $year = date('Y');
    }

    $start = array();
    $end = array();

    $start['year'] = $year;
    $start['month'] = ($quarter-1)*3 + 1;
    $start['day'] = 1;

    $end['year'] = $year;
    $end['month'] = ($quarter)*3;
    $end['day'] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, ($quarter)*3, $year);

    return array(
        new DateTime(implode('-', $start)),
        new DateTime(implode('-', $end)),
    );
}
```

Пользовать так:

```
list($begin, $end) = getQuarterInterval(2, 2014); // 2й квартал 2541 г.
echo $begin->format('d.m.Y').'<br />'; // 01.04.2541
echo $end->format('d.m.Y'); // 30.06.2541
```

Comment: тоже интересное решение :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private function getCurrentQuartalNumber() {
$mapArray = array(
    1 => '01',
    2 => '01',
    3 => '01',
    4 => '02',
    5 => '02',
    6 => '02',
    7 => '03',
    8 => '03',
    9 => '03',
    10 => '04',
    11 => '04',
    12 => '04'
);
return $mapArray[date('m')];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine($"Now {now} | ST: {getStartQuartal(now)} - END: {getEndQuartal(now)}");
}

public static DateTime getStartQuartal(DateTime dt_now)
{
    return new DateTime(dt_now.Year, (int)((dt_now.Month-1)/3)*3+1, 1);
}

public static DateTime getEndQuartal(DateTime dt_now)
{
    return new DateTime(dt_now.Year, (int)((dt_now.Month-1)/3)*3+3, 1);
}
```

Result:
Now 24.01.2024 12:51:49 | ST: 01.01.2024 0:00:00 - END: 01.03.2024 0:00:00